# Python where to put while loop wx.python systray

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, wxpython

I am having an issue figuring out where to put a while loop I have moved this thing around several times issues I am running into.

1. multiple systray icons and instances running
2. cannot pull up systray menu so no exit feature
3. no icon if I don't allow for MainLoop to execute etc

```html
import wx
import time

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'Connector Error Discovery'
TRAY_ICON = 'image.jpg'

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
  item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
  menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
  menu.AppendItem(item)
  return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
  def __init__(self):
    super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
    self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

  def CreatePopupMenu(self):
    menu = wx.Menu()
    create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
    return menu

  def set_icon(self, path):
    icon = wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(path))
    self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

  def on_left_down(self, event):
    print 'Tray icon was left-clicked.'

  def on_exit(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)

def looping():
  while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'hi'

def main():
  app = wx.PySimpleApp()
  TaskBarIcon()
  app.MainLoop(looping())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I completely remove the function looping, it works.

I do not understand what you are trying to do with the looping, but you certainly do it wrong.